# c# HttpResponseMessage - how to get X-Total-Pages from response and use it to get all results without pagination

Tags: c#, response-headers, gitlab-api

Hello I'm using  this to call to GitLab API:

`HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiPath);`

In this response there is headers > results view > X-Total-Pages key

[value in visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8dX3.png)

How to get its value?

Comment: Try response.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "X-Total");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i wrote this method to get list of tags from GIT API. I used **X-Total-Pages** instead **X-Total** and it worked to avoid API pagination results and get it all into on list:

```
                {
                    List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
                    List<Tag> one_site_of_tags = new List<Tag>();
                    string apiPath = WhichRepo(repository)[0] + "projects/" + appId + "/repository/tags";
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiPath);                   
                    string number_tag_sites = response.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "X-Total-Pages").Value.FirstOrDefault();                    
                   
                    for (int site = 1;
                        site <= Int16.Parse(number_tag_sites);
                        site++)
                    {
                        string apiPath2 = apiPath + "?page=" + site;
                        var content = await client.GetStringAsync(apiPath);
                        one_site_of_tags = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tag>>(content);
                        tags.AddRange(one_site_of_tags);
                    }                                        
                    
                    return tags;
                }
```